# Issues with iText7 creating acrofield forms, saving the pdf. When i open it, it cant be recognized by itext as acroform, so it cant find fields

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, itext

I have an application where I allow the user to draw rectangles on a pdf converted to png. I map the png coordinates of the rectangle that is drawn to the coordinates of the pdf (x,y, width, height) to make a field there. I programmatically assign values to these fields based on inputted information along with user information. When the user defines all the pdf fields for each pdf, they select the ones they want in the package. Combining merges the pdfs. I then save the pdf package, and when i open it I can see all the fields with the correct info populated. I want to give the user a chance to edit what was populated in the fields, as well as enter information in fields that couldnt be auto populated. After this, the user hits save (the path is the same), and then I have a "finalize" button that should make all the fields readonly. The problem is, when i attempt to run the finalize method, the PDfAcroForm is null. if i set iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm form = iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true) <- the true makes it an acroform again, but form.GetFormFields().Keys is null, so there is no fields found to make read only. I can set the form fields to be read only in the method I use to add the values however. My suspicion is when i run the method to merge pdfs, the acroform data is somehow lost.

Here is how i add the form fields:

````
`private void AddFieldsToPdf()
        {

            string definedUserDocsPath = Settings.Default.DefinedUserDocs;

            // Create new path within the "DefinedUserDocs" folder
            string newFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_pdfPath) + "_annotated.pdf";
            string newPath = Path.Combine(definedUserDocsPath, newFileName);

            // Load the existing PDF document
            using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDoc = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(_pdfPath), new PdfWriter(newPath)))
            {
                iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm form = iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);

                foreach (int pageIndex in pageRectangles.Keys)
                {
                    iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfPage page = pdfDoc.GetPage(pageIndex + 1); // Adjust for 1-based indexing
                    List<VariableField> variableFields = pageRectangles[pageIndex];

                    float pdfPageHeight = pages[pageIndex].Height;

                    foreach (VariableField vf in variableFields)
                    {
                        float pdfX = vf.Rect.Left;
                        float pdfY = pdfPageHeight - vf.Rect.Top;
                        float pdfWidth = vf.Rect.Width;
                        float pdfHeight = vf.Rect.Height;

                        if (vf.VariableType == "Signature")
                        {
                            PdfSignatureFormField signatureField = PdfFormField.CreateSignature(pdfDoc, new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(pdfX, pdfY - vf.Rect.Height, pdfWidth, pdfHeight));
                            signatureField.SetFieldName(vf.GetFormFieldName());
                            form.AddField(signatureField, page);
                        }

                        // Create a text form field with the name of the VariableType
                        PdfTextFormField field = PdfFormField.CreateText(pdfDoc,
                                            new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(pdfX, pdfY - vf.Rect.Height, pdfWidth, pdfHeight), vf.VariableType);

                        // field props here!
                        field.SetFieldName(vf.GetFormFieldName());

                        // Add the form field to the AcroForm and associate it with the page
                        form.AddField(field, page);

                    }
                }
                pdfDoc.Close();  // Save the PDF document.
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Form fields added successfully!");

            //Event to send path of newly defined pdf to listboxDefinedDocument on EditAccountForm
            PdfDefined?.Invoke(newPath);

            this.Close();

        }
```
And the methods for setting field values, combining pdf documents, and finalizing are:

```
private void FillFormFields(string inputPath, string outputPath, RFQ rfq, User user)
        {
            try
            {
                using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader pdfReader = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(inputPath))
                using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter pdfWriter = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter(outputPath))
                using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDocument = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter))
                {
                    iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm pdfForm = iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDocument, true);

                    if (pdfForm == null)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("No AcroForm found in the PDF.");
                    }

                    var fieldMapping = GenerateFieldMapping(rfq, user);
                    PopulatePdfFormFields(pdfForm, fieldMapping);
                    EmbedSignatureIfAvailable(pdfForm, pdfDocument);

                    pdfForm.SetGenerateAppearance(true);
                    pdfForm.RemoveXfaForm();
                    pdfDocument.GetCatalog().Remove(iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfName.Perms);
                    pdfDocument.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"An error occurred while filling the PDF fields: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void EmbedSignatureIfAvailable(iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm pdfForm, iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDocument)
        {
            string signatureImagePathBase = Settings.Default.CompanyAdditionals;
            string signatureImagePath = Path.Combine(signatureImagePathBase, "signature.png");

            if (!File.Exists(signatureImagePath)) return;

            var fieldsToRemove = new List<string>();

            foreach (var fieldEntry in pdfForm.GetFormFields())
            {
                if (!fieldEntry.Key.Contains("Signature")) continue;

                var signatureField = fieldEntry.Value;
                int pageNumber = pdfDocument.GetPageNumber(signatureField.GetWidgets()[0].GetPage());
                iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfPage page = pdfDocument.GetPage(pageNumber);
                iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle rect = signatureField.GetWidgets()[0].GetRectangle().ToRectangle();

                iText.Kernel.Pdf.Xobject.PdfImageXObject pdfImage = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.Xobject.PdfImageXObject(ImageDataFactory.Create(signatureImagePath));
                iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.PdfCanvas canvas = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.PdfCanvas(page);

                fieldsToRemove.Add(fieldEntry.Key);

                float xPosition = rect.GetLeft();
                float yPosition = rect.GetBottom();

                canvas.AddXObject(pdfImage, xPosition, yPosition - 10, rect.GetWidth());
            }

            foreach (var fieldKey in fieldsToRemove)
            {
                pdfForm.RemoveField(fieldKey);
            }
        }

        private void PopulatePdfFormFields(iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm pdfForm, Dictionary<string, string> fieldMapping)
        {
            foreach (var field in pdfForm.GetFormFields())
            {

                //field.Value.SetReadOnly(false);
                if (field.Key.Contains("CustomField"))
                {
                    field.Value.SetValue("");
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var mapping in fieldMapping)
                    {
                        if (field.Key.Contains(mapping.Key))
                        {
                            field.Value.SetValue(mapping.Value);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```
 private Dictionary<string, string> GenerateFieldMapping(RFQ rfq, User user)
        {
            //field mappings
            return new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                //Seller
                    {"UsersName", user.UsersName},
                    {"SBDVBE", user.SBDVBE},
                    {"TaxIDFein", user.TaxIDFein},
                    {"PhoneNumber", user.PhoneNumber},
                    {"EmailAddress", user.EmailAddress},
                    {"CompanyName", user.CompanyName},
                    {"CompanyAddress", user.CompanyAddress}, //NEED COMPANY FULL ADDRES?!?!?!?!
                    {"SellersPermit", user.SellersPermit},
                    //RFQ + Buyer
                    {"ContactEmail", rfq.ContactEmail},
                    {"ContactName", rfq.ContactName},
                    {"ContactPhoneNumber", rfq.ContactPhoneNumber},
                    {"AgencyRole", rfq.AgencyRole},
                    {"BuyerAgency", rfq.BuyerAgency},
                    {"BuyerAddress", rfq.BuyerAddress},
                    {"BuyerCity", rfq.BuyerCity},
                    {"BuyerState", rfq.BuyerState},
                    {"BuyerZip", rfq.BuyerZip},
                    //RFQ Specific
                    {"ExpirationDate", rfq.ExpirationDate.ToString("d")},
                    {"GuaranteeDate", rfq.GuaranteeDate.ToString("d")},
                    {"PriceGuarantee", rfq.PriceGuarantee.ToString()},
                    {"QuoteNumber", rfq.QuoteNumber},
                    {"RFQNumber", rfq.RFQNumber },
                    {"TaxRate", rfq.taxRate.ToString()},
                    {"Date:Current", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("d")}
                
            };
        }


private void CombinePDFs(ListBox listBox)
        {
            List<string> folderPaths = new List<string>
            {
                Settings.Default.BaseDir,
                Settings.Default.GeneratedDocuments,
                Settings.Default.UserFiles,
                Settings.Default.DefinedUserDocs,
                Settings.Default.UserFiles_Clean,
                Settings.Default.CompanyAdditionals,
                Settings.Default.ArchivedEmails,
                Settings.Default.CompanyLogos
            };

            CombinePDFsInOrder(listBox, folderPaths);
        }


        private void CombinePDFsInOrder(ListBox listBox, List<string> folderPaths)
        {
            try
            {
                string basePath = Settings.Default.Packages;
                string outputFilePath = Path.Combine(basePath, $"Package_{_selectedRFQ.RFQNumber}_unflattened.pdf");

                using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter pdfWriter = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter(outputFilePath))
                using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument mergedPdfDoc = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(pdfWriter))
                {
                    PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(mergedPdfDoc).SetCloseSourceDocuments(true);

                    foreach (var item in listBox.Items)
                    {
                        string selectedPDF = item.ToString();
                        foreach (string folderPath in folderPaths)
                        {
                            string pdfPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, selectedPDF);
                            if (File.Exists(pdfPath))
                            {
                                string tempFilledPdfPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".pdf");
                                FillFormFields(pdfPath, tempFilledPdfPath, _selectedRFQ, _user);

                                using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument sourcePdfDoc = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(tempFilledPdfPath)))
                                {
                                    // Merge the source document into the merged document
                                    merger.Merge(sourcePdfDoc, 1, sourcePdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages());
                                }

                                File.Delete(tempFilledPdfPath);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (iText.Kernel.PdfException pdfEx)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"PDF Error: {pdfEx.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            catch (IOException ioEx)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"I/O Error: {ioEx.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

private void buttonReviewPackage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string outputFilePath = Path.Combine(Settings.Default.Packages, "Package_" + _selectedRFQ.RFQNumber.ToString() + "_unflattened.pdf");
            GenerateQuoteDocument();
            CombinePDFs(listBoxPackageDocuments);

            // Open the generated PDF for review
            OpenPDFWithDefaultViewer(outputFilePath);
        }



        private void FlattenAndFinalizePDF(string filePath)
        {
            string destFileName = $"Package_{_selectedRFQ.RFQNumber}_flattened.pdf";
            string destPdfPath = Path.Combine(Settings.Default.Packages, destFileName);

            using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDoc = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(filePath), new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter(destPdfPath)))
            {
                iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm form = iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);

                if (form != null)
                {
                    foreach (string fieldName in form.GetFormFields().Keys)
                    {
                        iText.Forms.Fields.PdfFormField field = form.GetField(fieldName);

                        // Set the field to read-only
                        field.SetReadOnly(true);
                    }                
                }
                pdfDoc.Close();
            }

 private void buttonFlattenFinalize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```

```

            string outputFilePath = Path.Combine(Settings.Default.Packages, "Package_" + _selectedRFQ.RFQNumber.ToString() + "_unflattened.pdf");

            // Flatten and finalize the PDF
            FlattenAndFinalizePDF(outputFilePath);

            //File.SetAttributes(outputFilePath, FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
            // Prompt user with a message after flattening
            MessageBox.Show("PDF has been flattened and finalized.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);`
`

I noticed I can set the fields to read only when i populate the fields with values in PopulatePdfFormFields(), but upon saving the package of pdfs, and attempting to flatten/ make read only, nothing happens as it isnt recognized as an accroform by itext.


I have tried even making the file read only, but it still allows the fields that I added to be modifiable. Ideally, the flatten and finalize function just gets all the field form names and loops thru and sets to readOnly, effectively finalizing the form. My suspicions lie in the combination/merging of the pdfs somehow causing the resulting pdf to not retain all the field information from the merged pdfs. When i view the combined pdf, I can see all the fields along with their field names.
````

Comment: As far as I know `PdfMerger` does not copy form fields. You may consider truly flattening the forms before merging. Alternatively you can merge using the `PdfDocument.CopyPagesTo` overload with the `IPdfPageExtraCopier` parameter. Use a `PdfPageFormCopier` there. Beware, though, that PDF forms are not separated by page or something. Thus, if you copy multiple fields with the same name into the merged PDF, they'll all become widgets of the same field and, therefore, will have the same value!

Comment: In the current iText develop branch (8.0.2-SNAPSHOT) there are changes considering what happened when adding form fields with the same name, you now can provide a strategy class that decides whether the fields with the same name become one field or are renamed  or whatever.